# Change color of the div shown in the window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the colors of the `div`s from skyblue to yellow, when a specific `div` appears **OR** goes through the middle of the window. I have been building my own logic which works fine when I scroll the page up and down slowly. But it doesn't work when I scroll the page fast. I have inserted a button which takes the page to the fourth `div` (Box - 5) from the 100 `div`s. When the fourth `div` appears the background color does not switch, I have the keep scrolling up and down for my logic to change the fourth background color. The button is placed at the bottom of the page.

So I need help in making a better logic to changing the `div`'s background color when the `div` is at or goes through the middle of the window, no matter the page is being scrolled fast or slow **OR** the page being 
directly shifted to a specific `div`. Thanks

`My index.html:`

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
  current = 0;

for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.id = "box";
  box.innerHTML = "Box - " + (y + 1);
  content.appendChild(box);
}

content.children[current].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (this.oldScroll > this.scrollY) {
    if (current >= 1) {
      var previous_box = content.children[current - 1];
      if ((this.scrollY + this.innerHeight / 2) < previous_box.offsetTop + previous_box.clientHeight) {
        content.children[current].style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
        current--;
        content.children[current].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (current < 99) {
      var next_box = content.children[current + 1];
      if ((this.scrollY + this.innerHeight / 2) > next_box.offsetTop) {
        content.children[current].style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
        current++;
        content.children[current].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      }
    }
  }
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var y = content.children[4].offsetTop - (content.children[4].clientHeight / 4);
  window.scrollTo(0, y);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation {
  min-width: 620px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15% auto 15% auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: black 1px solid;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin: 0% auto 15% auto;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<button>GO TO BOX 5</button>
```

Comment: in your measure of scroll fast - is that achievable by mouse - or are you saying it only occurs by a programmed scroll (as in - when I scroll using click) - so is the problem only with a programmed scroll ?

Comment: Im trying to change the color of the div when the div appears in middle of the screen/window. Similar to how the videos auto-playing in Instagram, 9GAG and Facebook when any specific video player appears in the middle of the screen. My logic doesn't work when I set the Scroll-Y to a specific div's position, as seen when the `GO TO BOX 5` is clicked. My logic is not able to fit in this situation and need help for it, I can't think of a good method.

Comment: Ok, I think you might need to trigger the handler to simulate the scroll - onscroll is detecting a mouse scroll (perhaps) - maybe a window.dispatchEvent('scroll');

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @DavidBray looks useful, ill check it out later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
  current = 0;

for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.id = "box";
  box.innerHTML = "Box - " + (y + 1);
  content.appendChild(box);
}

content.children[current].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

window.onscroll = function() {
  for(var i=0;i<content.children.length;i++){
     var top = content.children[i]. getBoundingClientRect().top;
     var height = top+content.children[i].clientHeight;
     var halfWindow = window.innerHeight*0.5;
     if(top<halfWindow&&height>halfWindow){
       content.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
     }
     else{
       content.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
     }
  }

}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var y = content.children[4].offsetTop - (content.children[4].clientHeight / 4);
  window.scrollTo(0, y);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation {
  min-width: 620px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15% auto 15% auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: black 1px solid;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin: 0% auto 15% auto;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<button>GO TO BOX 5</button>
```

Comment: When I place a div in the middle of the screen, it doesn't change color

Comment: What do you mean by placing div in the middle of the screen. Were you adding any more divs dynamically?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xwjcNaWZzF5LDXrsQ1Q1p2gtnkU413Xm/view?usp=sharing - here. I will be appending more divs later on

Comment: I see the the color changed in the video. Are you talking about the first div, which did not change color till scrolled?

Comment: In the video, Box - 2 was scrolled to the middle of the screen, but it did not change color.